# Problems including Box2D to Cocos2D v3/Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm trying to install Box2D (separately because I'm using cocos2d v3 which only has chipmunk). But I'm stumbling upon a slight problem, it says I'm missing two header files (file not found), but they are indeed there. I'll add some screenshots trying to clarify the problem. Any idea how I can make Xcode find the files that are actually there?

...Bummer I can't post images yet, so no screenshots I guess :/

Edit: The files are --> `#include <Box2D/Common/b2Settings.h>` and 
`#include <Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2WeldJoint.h>`

Comment: You can copy & paste as text almost anything from Xcode, including build logs and what not. Screenshots are not a good idea for errors on SO as they get scaled down and become hard/impossible to read. As to your problem: pretty sure the solution is found by editing header search paths to point to the Box2D root folder. Also you have to use the other search paths field, there's user header search path and header search path, only one of them will work for box2d due to its < > style imports.

Comment: Ya, your supposed to use the "user header search path" but there is no such thing (at least I couldn't find it) so I added it to the header search path. Any idea how to find the user header search path in Xcode Version 6.1?

Comment: Never mind, I had only on show the basic, and not all... found it now =)